# Get edges inside a sub-graph

Tags: cytoscape.js

I don't see an easy way to get the edges of a sub-graph, that is the edges that connect a collection of nodes.

The best I can do is to compute the connected edges minus the outgoing edges:

```
function getInsideEdges(nodes) {
    var connectedEdges = nodes.connectedEdges();
    var complement = nodes.absoluteComplement();
    var outgoingEdges = nodes.edgesWith(complement);
    var insideEdges = connectedEdges.difference(outgoingEdges);
    return insideEdges;
}
```

That seems really awkward, considering a lot of other operations are simplified by the API. What am I missing?

edit: the first solution I tried doesn't work : `nodes.edgesWith(nodes)` return the same set as `nodes.connectedEdges()`.

```
var cy = cytoscape({headless:true,elements:{
    nodes:[
        {data:{id:'n1'}},
        {data:{id:'n2'}},
        {data:{id:'n3'}}
    ],
    edges:[
        {data:{id:'e1-2',source:'n1',target:'n2'}},
        {data:{id:'e1-3',source:'n1',target:'n3'}},
        {data:{id:'e2-3',source:'n2',target:'n3'}}
    ]
}});
var nodes = cy.nodes();
var subgraphNodes = cy.$('#n1,#n2');
// we want to obtain the edges inside that subgraph: the collection ['e1-2']

subgraphNodes.connectedEdges().size();
// -> 3

subgraphNodes.edgesWith(subgraphNodes).size();
// -> 3

subgraphNodes.connectedEdges().difference(subgraphNodes.edgesWith(subgraphNodes.absoluteComplement())).size();
// -> 1

// another solution
subgraphNodes.outgoers('edge').intersection(subgraphNodes.incomers('edge')).size();
// -> 1
```

---

**edit**: @maxkfranz fixed cytoscape.js so that `subgraphNodes.edgesWith( subgraphNodes )` now properly returns the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subgraphNodes.edgesWith( subgraphNodes )` -- since you want edges inside (i.e. connected to nodes in) the subgraph

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that, but it doesn't work : it returns every edge connected to subgraphNodes. But I only want those for which both ends belong to subgraphNodes. See my edit.

Comment: In that case, you've found [a bug](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/971), so my original answer ought to be correct but is just buggy.